# If db column can be NULL set required input?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

is there a way how can I ask if the chosen column can't be null that php should add value "required" (html5) to the input?

Trying to outline the idea:

```
$vys = mysqli_query($db, "some query here"); 
while($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vys)){
    echo "<input type='text' name='".$arr['name of column']."' value='' ".(canBeNull($arr['name of column']) ? "require" : "")." />";
}
```

After this, some '`INSERT VALUES(...) INTO table`' would follow.. This example is supposed to '`echo`' all columns from table so user can fill them up. And yes, I know, that the only query which can be processed with mysqli_fetch_assoc is '`SELECT * FROM column`', but I was thinking that this would be very helpful for registration forms, where when registering new user, name and surname is mandatory (`NOT NULL` column), but nickname is optional (`NULL` column). And when there are tens of input fields that should be very time-saving.

Don't you please know, how this stuff can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` query before hand to get the column list.  Then there is a Null column that is either set to Yes or No.

Comment: rather more 'expensive' than dealing with it in your code logic.

Comment: Yes, it is not smart to run this before every select, that is for sure.  You would have to weigh your options, if this is only run once in a while for pages that have forms, like a profile page for instance, then it shouldn't be harmful.  MySQL should load the column list very fast.

Answer (score 0):

if you execute a query like:

```
$q = $this->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
$q->execute();
```

it returns a array like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Field] => dataid
        [0] => dataid
        [Type] => int(11)
        [1] => int(11)
        [Null] => NO
        [2] => NO
        [Key] => PRI
        [3] => PRI
        [Default] => 
        [4] => 
        [Extra] => auto_increment
        [5] => auto_increment
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Field] => text
        [0] => text
        [Type] => varchar(255)
        [1] => varchar(255)
        [Null] => NO
        [2] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [3] => 
        [Default] => 
        [4] => 
        [Extra] => 
        [5] => 
    )

)
```

You could check it like that. Seems like this should be baked into the business logic of the php though and not have to check with the db maybe a attribute in the class the sets $notNull to true in the construct

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli has extra method to get metadata from queries. [mysqli_stmt::result_metadata](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php)

Example

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM friends");
$stmt->execute();

/* get resultset for metadata */
$result = $stmt->result_metadata();

/* retrieve field information from metadata result set */
$fields = $result->fetch_fields(); // array of std objects
```

And check what field could be null.

```
(!($field->flags & MYSQLI_NOT_NULL_FLAG))
    echo $field->name;
```

Other flags could be obtained here: [Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php#constantmysqli-not-null-flag)